# Want to select all the mentioned data in single query form multiple data

Tags: sql, postgresql

**i am using postgres db

My tables are as follows

**table 1::**

```
user_details
```

**columns::**

```
user_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,organisation
```

**table2**

```
user_roles
```

**cols::**

```
id,user_name,role
```

**Constraints::**

```
FK==>user_roles(user_name) reference user_details(user_id)
```

SQL Query which I have written is:

```
SELECT  ud.user_id,
    ud.organisation,
    CONCAT(COALESCE(ud.first_name,''),' ',COALESCE(ud.middle_name,''),' ',COALESCE(ud.last_name,'')) AS full_name,
    ur.role
    FROM user_details ud
    INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ud.user_id = ur.username;
```

which gives me data as::

```
user_id | organisation   | full_name         | role
--------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------
user1   | organisation 1 | first middle last | ROLE_REGISTEREDUSER
user1   | organisation 1 | first middle last | ROLE_ADMIN
user 2  | org 2          | first middle last | ROLE_REGISTEREDUSER
user 2  | org 2          | first middle last | ROLE_ADMIN
```

As there are multiple roles, I am getting 2 rows for each user. Is there any way to concat the roles as well and get single row for each user with roles concatenated as follows:

```
user_id | organisation   | full_name         | role
--------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------------------
user1   | organisation 1 | first middle last | ROLE_REGISTEREDUSER,ROLE_ADMIN
user 2  | org 2          | first middle last | ROLE_REGISTEREDUSER,ROLE_ADMIN
```

Comment: On a sidenote: Be consistent with your names. From the table name `user_details` I thought there'd be a `users` table containing the users and this details table for multiple details per user. (I even feared a key/value table, as this is not called `user_addresses`, `user_hobbies` or the like.) But then I saw it's just the users table with a confusing name. Then in this table a user has an ID and a name consisting of three parts. In `user_roles`, however there is a single name called `user_name`. This, however, is (luckily) not the cocatenated name, but the ID. Why is it called name here then?

Comment: As to the data model: I would expect two more tables: one for the organizations and one for the roles. Without them you may end up with organizations and roles multiplied and misspelled ('organisation 1', 'organization 1', 'Organisation 1', 'org 1' and 'ROLE_REGISTEREDUSER', 'ROLE_REGISTERED_USER', ...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions @Thorsten i do have a table which maintains the role string ROLE_REGISTEREDUSER etc but i just not meentioned it in question just want to convey my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining one role, join a string of all roles a user has. You get this by aggregating per user name and using `string_agg`.

```
select
  ud.user_id,
  ud.organisation,
  concat_ws(' ', ud.first_name, ud.middle_name, ud.last_name) as full_name,
  ur.roles
from user_details ud
left join
(
  select username, string_agg(role, ',' order by role) as roles
  from user_roles
  group by username
) ur on ur.username = ud.user_id;
```

Make this an inner join, if you only want users that have roles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You need an aggregation query.  If you want the result as a string:

```
SELECT ud.user_id, ud.organisation,
       CONCAT(COALESCE(ud.first_name, ''), ' ', COALESCE(ud.middle_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(ud.last_name,'')) AS full_name,
       STRING_AGG(ur.role, ',' ORDER BY ur.role) as roles
FROM user_details ud INNER JOIN
     user_roles ur
     ON ud.user_id = ur.username
GROUP BY user_id, organization, full_name;
```

Often in Postgres, an array is more useful than a string.  You can use the equivalent `array_agg()` for an array result instead.